# beginner question: Why do I need to type "PD." for read_csv, but after i create a dataframe, i don't need to typ "PD." anymore

Tags: python, pandas

sorry, im a new beginner in python, i have a quick question on the following. Thanks in advance!

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("name.csv") ## why do i need the "pd." part for this


df.info ## why do i NOT need the "pd." part for these?
df.sort_values ## why do i NOT need the "pd." part for these?
```

Comment: no assignemnt, im just trying to understand the basic logic here.

I am just importing a CSV file and creating a dataframe from it.

just curious why i need the "pd." prefix when using "read_csv), while I only need the "df." prefix for some of the other functions like info, sortvalues, etc

Comment: @BALearningPython you need `pd.read_csv` because *there is no variable `read_csv` defined in your code. However, you've imported the pandas library, and that module is assigned to the variable `pd`. You can now access *attributes* of that moduel object using `.whatever`

Comment: As for `df.info`, you don't need `pd` because *`.info` is not an attribute of the module object`pd`, it is an attribute of the dataframe object `df`*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you so much! this was a GREAT explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Everything in your python code, whether it be a variable, something you have imported, or anything else, is an **object**. Objects have **attributes** which can be referenced using `<object>.<attribute name>`.

When you use `import pandas as pd` you create a new object, stored in the variable called `pd`. This object has a lot of attributes, one of them being the function `read_csv`.

When you use the function `pd.read_csv`, you create a new object, which you are storing in a variable called `df`. `info` and `sort_values` are attributes of the object stored in the `df` variable not the `pd` variable so you don't need `pd.` to use them. All you need is the `df.`.

Comment: ahh thank you so much! very helpful explanation

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` is a module. Basically a file or set of files that contain functions, classes and variables that you can use in your code.

You `import` the contents of that module into your file and give it the name `pd`.

```
import pandas as pd
```

This is shorthand for:

```
import pandas
pd = pandas
```

When you want to reference the variables and functions in that `module` you use dot notation.

```
<module name>.<variable, class, or function in module>
```

In your case, you are using the function `read_csv` inside the `pandas` module and assigning the result to the variable name `df`.

```
df = pd.read_csv("name.csv")
```

`df` is a [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) object with `info` and `sort_values` attributes which can also be accessed by dot notation.

```
df.info
df.sort_values
```

Dot notation for an object follows.

```
<object name>.<attribute(variable) or method(function)>
```

As an aside, every variable name used in your python file must be defined somehow. By assignment(`=`), `import`, or definition.

By default, python includes some [built-in constants](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#built-in-consts) and [functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-funcs) that you can reference, but everything else should follow those rules.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was incredbly helpful